# Migration M2 to M2

Tags: migration, magento2.3.4

Something is wrong with our Databse, i'm sure of that.
Now i want to kill all problems en start fresh.

When we started we used the Ubertheme Data migration tool for our Magento 1 shop to migrate to Magento 2 which we use for the last 3 years. But somewere inside of the database is some bad not great migrated data which causes these problems (this is what i hope at least). To eleminate this hunch i want to migrate our existing data into a fresh database. Normally you can simply take a export en do it like so. BUT for somekind of reason our export function is not really working flawless so this is not a real option.

Is there a 'simple' way to migrate the existing data from our Magento 2 Databse into a fresh Magento 2 Database, and keep all relations in-tact.

Thanks in advanced for potentially helping us with this question.

Comment: Genuinely I think you should have used Magento data migration tool with load of instruction documents, or consider our Magento upgrade package instead of using an integrated tool.

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want to try to backup and then restore your Magento 2 database to a new db you can use MySql commands from the DB host :

BACKUP

```
mysqldump -h localhost -uUSERNAME -pPASSWORD M2DBNAME > backup.db.sql
```

RESTORE

```
mysql -h localhost -uUSERNAME -pPASSWORD M2NEWDBNAME < backup.db.sql
```

You will then need to configure M2 to use M2NEWDBNAME

If however you believe your M2 database is corrupted, I don't think this will help as all data will simply be backed up and restored. There is no other simple EXPORT / IMPORT process that will rebuild your store data.